# Disabling three finger scroll to top on Firefox without disabling three finger back/forwards

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad, macos, multi-touch

If I switch "swipe with three fingers" to two fingers, Mac disables the "three finger swipe up" (e.g. page up/down). But I want to keep three fingers to go back and forth (horizontally), while disabling page up/down (vertically). Is this possible?

[image: apple settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Firefox open `about:config`:

Search for `browser.gesture.swipe.down` and `browser.gesture.swipe.up` and delete both entries.

Restart Firefox.

Comment: This only works in FireFox, presumably?